# Reverse DNS (PTR) Problems Exist

Tags: server, dns, cpanel, whm, reverse-dns

I face an anonymous issue in my reverse PTR record in WHM Panel.
I Update all PTR record Using SSH command and adding a DNS Zone
Just You can See the image

[here is SSH Command and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtjwP.png)

[DNS Zone name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEPyI.png)

[DNS Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBXLP.png)

Now when I visit the Email Deliverability menu from whm panel than my DKIM & SPF Record is valid
But My Reverse DNS (PTR) Problems Exist

And I face two different errors in same place.
But It shows randomly

Some time shows these errors

```
There is no reverse DNS configured for the IP address (50.2.223.14) that the system uses to send this domain’s outgoing email.

To fix this problem, create the following PTR record at “rdns1.serverhubdns.com” and “rdns2.serverhubdns.com”:
```

When I refresh this page again and again the errors changed randomly  and show these error

```
The system sends the domain “eothan.brmidia.info” in the SMTP handshake for this domain’s email. “eothan.brmidia.info” does not resolve to any IP addresses.

To fix this problem, create a DNS “A” record for “eothan.brmidia.info” whose value is “50.2.223.14”.
```

And when I try to add DNS A record here shows A record already exits

How can I solve this issue?